# how to adjust fill the space of uitextfield with other view/uitextfield if one is hidden in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have 3 `uitextfield's` and a button , when i make the first `uitextfield` as hidden i want the other two to move up automatically and fill the space of the first `uitextfield's` space .

I have tried a way by giving a `uitextfield height constrain`t and then making it zero when hidden

```
@IBOutlet weak var newVirtualIDheight: NSLayoutConstraint!
newVirtualIDheight.constant = 0
```

but i am not satisfied with the solution , the `uitextfield` size differs in different screens in autolayout, is there any other way ??

Please help

Comment: using stackview you can do this.

Comment: Are you need to move Top textfield to higher?

Comment: @KKRocks can you please provide me with some reference ? thank you

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu no not higher , i want to make it invisible on runtime and move the below uitextfields to fill the space of hidden uitextfield

Comment: refer this link for example : https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/25/uistackview-stretch-content/

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the constrain for the parent as well.

```
@IBOutlet weak var layoutsForTextFields: NSLayoutConstraint!
layoutsForTextFields.constant = totalHeight - newVirtualIDheight.frame.size.height

@IBOutlet weak var newVirtualIDheight: NSLayoutConstraint!
newVirtualIDheight.constant = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `stack views` or , add `vertical` `constraints` to the first `text field` and change those when you `hide/show` the text field.

I have created a video tutorial for you. here is the link [hide text fields using constraints.](https://youtu.be/EBulMWMoFuw) for it.
(please skip from 6.30 min to 10.30) , sorry for that. I made it quick and no time to trim. again sorry.

Comment: i very much appreciate your effort by making a video on the spot , i will try it and let you know , thanks

Answer (score 0):

A better option to use a scroll view and move the text field higher. So It will fulfill your requirement I think.

Let me know is it helpful on not.

Comment: i am using a scrollview , but when i hide a view inside scrollview , how will the other views automatically fill the space ??